# Parse text and get value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many links:

```
var one = '/news/local/edit?user=marcus&owner=ffff';
var two = '/news/other/edit?user=josh&owner=ddd';
var three = '/news/local/edit?user=john';
var four = '/news/local/test/marcus/edit?owner=aaaa&user=ady';
```

How can I get from these links the value of `user`?

This should return:

```
one = 'marcus';
two = 'josh';
three = 'john';
four = 'ady';
```

The result can be in an array.

Comment: Where are you getting these links? Are they hard-coded strings in your code, or are they part of the `scr=` attribute in anchor tags, or ?

Comment: yes, there are attributes src

Comment: Never seen so many answers so quick.

Comment: You can change the function found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter) to look at your variables instead of `window.location.search`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to extract the query string parameters. Please refer the below question.

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

[**sample fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NeRK5/)

#### related code from the answer edited according to the context here:

```
function getParameterByName(name,url) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var one = '/news/local/edit?user=marcus&owner=ffff';
var two = '/news/other/edit?user=josh&owner=ddd';
var three = '/news/local/edit?user=john';
var four = '/news/local/test/marcus/edit?user=ady&owner=aaaa';

alert(getParameterByName("user",one));
alert(getParameterByName("user",two));
alert(getParameterByName("user",three));
alert(getParameterByName("user",four));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, more failsafe:

```
var str = '/news/local/edit?user=marcus&owner=ffff';
var one = str.split('user=')[1].split('&')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Or by searching and not spliting.

```
var capture = one.substring(one.indexOf("user=")+5);
var one = capture.substring(0, capture.indexOf("&"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
one = one.replace(/.*?user\=([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\&*.*/g, '$1')
two = two.replace(/.*?user\=([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\&*.*/g, '$1')
three = three.replace(/.*?user\=([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\&*.*/g, '$1')
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be:

`'/asd/?user=andy&algo=mas'.replace(/^.+user=([^\&]+).+$/, '$1') // returns 'andy'`

Answer (score 0):

This parser may do it for you ;)

```
function parseUser(str){
  var firstPart = str.substr(str.indexOf('user=') + 5); // +5 because the length of 'user='
  if(str.indexOf('&') !== -1)
    return firstPart.substr(0, firstPart.indexOf('&'));
  else
    return firstPart;
}
```

Comment: If you wish to use it other then 'user', be aware the length in the 2nd line!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Regular expression to capture the user:

```
var one = '/news/local/edit?user=marcus&owner=ffff';

var userOne = /user=([^&]+)/.exec(one)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1113766  with just a small modification to receive as parameter the string were you want to look for the value.

```
function getParameterByName(name, path) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(path);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tjdragon/T62T2/